# Webmatrix - deploying only certain files

Tags: webmatrix

I have a project I'm deploying using WebMatrix.  Is there a way to exclude certain files from the deployment e.g. perhaps some text files I may have in my project's directories?

Answer (score 1):

When you use Webmatrix deployment mechanism it will show you what files it is going to deploy.

Simply uncheck the files you don't want to deploy.

Comment: but then I have to manually de-select the files I don't ever want to publish each time I publish?? isn't there a way to permanently exclude certain files?